# SCSS: Select root class, then parent class and apply rules to child

Tags: css, sass

Unfortunately I haven't find a better title for this, but code says more than words.

I want the following CSS output:

```
.team-revolution-top-bar-marquee-is-active .team-revolution-top-bar-content {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Here is the minifed scss code:

```
.team-revolution-top-bar {
    &-marquee-is-active {
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    &-content {
         flex-grow: 1;
         padding: 0.4rem;

        @at-root &-marquee-is-active {
             background-color: yellow;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried around with `&` and `@at-root` but nothing really worked.

Is this possible with SCSS or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Then it might be time for an `extended` `silent` class.

```
%teamRevolution-bgC {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.teamRevolution-topBar {
  &-marquee-isActive {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    
    @extend %teamRevolution-bgC;
  }
  &-content {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 0.4rem;
    
    @extend %teamRevolution-bgC;
  }
}
```

```
.teamRevolution-topBar-marquee-isActive, .teamRevolution-topBar-content {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.teamRevolution-topBar-marquee-isActive {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.teamRevolution-topBar-content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 0.4rem;
}
```